# Change one cell data type in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have dataframe in which the third column is calculated by `df$pct <- percent(df$pct)`.

Sample:

```
df <- structure(list(Jan = c(1.52, 582.58), Feb = c(5.97, 312.94)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Code:

```
df$pct <- df[, 2]/df[, 1] - 1
df <- df %>%
  # mutate_if(is.numeric, ~round(., 2))
  mutate_at(vars(Jan, Feb), funs(round(., 2))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(pct), funs(round(., 4)))

df$pct <- percent(df$pct)
```

Out:

[image]

Now I want to replace the cell in red circle by the value calculated by `5.97 - 1.52`, so I use `df[1, 3] <- (df[1, 2] - df[1, 1])`, is it possible to change it to `4.45` instead of `292.76%`?

The desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df[1, 3] <- scales::percent(df[1, 2] - df[1, 1], scale = 1, accuracy = 0.01)
```

However, a simple `paste0` would also do here :

```
df[1, 3] <- paste0(df[1, 2] - df[1, 1], '%')
```

---

You can do :

```
df[1, 3] <- df[1, 2] - df[1, 1]
df
#     Jan    Feb  pct
#1   1.52   5.97 4.45
#2 582.58 312.94 -46%
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if you get my expected result. In fact, I want convert `percentage` format to `float` for cell `df[1, 3]`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `df[1, 2] - df[1, 1]` then? Can you provide data in a reproducible format to test our answer?

Comment: @ahbon `df[1, 3] <- df[1, 2] - df[1, 1]` gives your output, right?

Comment: emm, no, it gives `445.00%` for cell `df[1, 3]`, not `4.45`.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = data.frame(pct = c(4.45, -0.4628))
df$pct <- ifelse(df$pct > 1, df$pct, scales::percent(df$pct)) # this makes pct to be a character vector though
```